# Helm: How to iterate over 2 lists to get values from the same indexes?

Tags: go, cloud, kubernetes-helm

I would like to iterate over 2 lists at the same time and get values from identical indexes from both lists
template.yaml:

```
{{- $values1 := splitList ", " .Values.values1 }}
{{- $values2 := splitList ", " .Values.values2 }}
{{- range $index, $value1 := $values1 }}
{{- range $index, $value2 := $values2 }}
- data1: "something/{{$value1}}"
  data2: {{ $value2 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values:

```
values1: "data1_1, data1_2"
values2: "data2_1, data2_2"
```

The result I get:

```
- data1: "something/data1_1"
  data2: data2_1
- data1: "something/data1_1"
  data2: data2_2
- data1: "something/data1_2"
  data2: data2_1
- data1: "something/data1_2"
  data2: data2_2
```

The result I want:

```
- data1: "something/data1_1"
  data2: data2_1
- data1: "something/data1_2"
  data2: data2_2
```

Can someone help me obtain that result?

Comment: something along the lines of `{{ $value2 := $values2[$index] }}` instead of the second `range` loop